# Не работает PHP на хостинге

Tags: php, wordpress, хостинг

Ситуация следующая.

Залил на хостинг сайт, привязал домен. Когда открываю сайт, то отображает ошибку "HTTP ERROR 500". В логе была ошибка: "PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_header()  ...".

Какие меры я предпринимал?

- Ради интереса закомментировал строку, где возникает ошибка, то есть get_header(). В итоге возникла другая фатальная ошибка. И знаете где? На месте следующего PHP-кода.
- Что ещё пробовал? Менял версию PHP, но безрезультатно.

Обратился в техподдержку, они сказали, что *"проблема возникает при попытке обратится к неиницилизированному классу... "*.

В общем, **почему может не работать php-код на хостинге?, как сделать классы инициализированными?**

Comment: Может файлы не долили, `get_header()` это что-то уже нестандартная функция.

Comment: Покажите код с вызовом get_header. Вы закомментировали всю строку? Там же скорее всего было какое-то присваивание.

Comment: @ЕгорБанин, просто `<?php get_header(); ?>`

Comment: Аааа. Это Вордпрес? Если так, то добавьте тег в вопрос и напишите, что у вас вордпрес. Так вам гораздо быстрее помогут.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я перенёс на хостинг тему, а надо было весь ВП.

Мне аж неловко от такой грубой ошибки.

Это как, если бы мне заказали сделать, например, телефон, я его сделал бы, а заказчику отправил бы только экран от него.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка не PHP на хостинге, а в вашем CMS!
Видимо что-то потеряли при установке сайта на хостинг или случайно удалили? Возможно htaccess неверный или отсутствует.
Переустановите CMS (лучше чистую версию) - это самый верный способ. потом уже перенесите пользовательские данные: бд и template

Comment: Переустановка CMS серьезно?  Тут речь не об ошибке CMS, а о смене хостинга. Сайт то рабочий, и неуказанно что он вообще на CMS. Скорее всего сайт самописный или на фреймворке типа Laravel Yii.

Comment: @китайецИзКитая кажется всё-таки вордпрес.

Answer (score 0):

У вас не подключен файл с функциями. Точнее подключен но по старой директории. Желательно использовать DIR или $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] в require или include. Ошибка скорее всего связана с тем, что вы вызываете функции но их нет, точнее не верно подключены библиотеки с самими функциями. Возможно путь к файлу у вас указан явный но так как вы хостинг сменили он может отличаться.